# Grid doesn't fill available space when using DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an ActiPro ThemedDataGrid (inherits from WPF DataGrid).
I'm setting the header DataTemplate with a Grid, but it is not taking all the available space.
This is my DataTemplate

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyKey" DataType="ViewModels:FieldVM">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Label}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" />
                <local:MyUserControl Name="units" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AvailableUnits}" Value="{x:Null}" >
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="units" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsUnitAware, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UnitConversionGrid}}}" Value="False" >
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" TargetName="units" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I want the Grid to use all the available space so they look even throughout all the columns in the DataGrid.

How do I make the Grid in the DataTemplate to take all the available space within the header of each column?
I want the rows to use the same height in all the columns.
For example if the height of the rows is 30 and 70 in the first column then I want all the other columns to have the same distribution.

Example:

```
---------------------------------
| Row1 with  |Row1       | Row1  |
| More Text  |           |       |
|---------------------------------
| Row2 with  |Row2       |Row2   |
| More Text  |           |       |
----------------------------------
```

How can I make the rows throughout the columns to take the height of the bigger Rows?

Thanks,

Another simplified example:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ActiproSoftware.Windows.Controls.DataGrid;assembly=ActiproSoftware.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <controls:ThemedDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-10.556,-1.744" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="507" Height="310">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="50">
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}}, Path=Height}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="40" DockPanel.Dock="Top">Value1 Test</TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="50">Value2 Test With Four Lines</TextBlock>
                            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="Value3" HorizontalAlignment="Center" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Grid.Row="0"/>
                            <ComboBox  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.Header>
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </controls:ThemedDataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: probably by changing or removing shared size group A , Remove it completely and they will stretch to the entire container.

Comment: @eranotzap I have already tried without the SharedSizeGroup property without success, the height of the Grid each column is different.

Comment: @Blam The second row is a UserControl not a standard WPF combobox

Comment: Don't know where I thought I say combobox.  You have columns and the rows don't even line up.  Can you post a picture?

Comment: Did you try replacing the Grid with a DockPanel?

Comment: @Rhyous Yes, I tried with a DockPanel and I get the same behavior

Comment: I have added a simplified example to better see the problem. You can easily replace ThemedDataGrid with DataGrid if you don't have ActiPro

Answer (score 0):

First, check to make sure your DataGrid is as big as you think it is (the header may actually be filling correctly).

Next, try binding the width property of your Grid to the width of the DataGrid, something like this:

```
   Width="{Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" Path="ActualWidth"}"
```

You may need to do the same to the holding border element.

Your XAML also contains some DockPanel properties which seems out of place given there is no dock panel container. That shouldn't break anything, but you may want to remove it anyways.

Comment: I think you are on the right direction, however this makes the Header take the Height(I replaced Width from your reply) of the whole DataGrid, so my DataGrid shows just the Header. I tried using DataGridColumnHeader in the AncestorType but got the same behavior. Which AncestorType should it be?

Comment: I have added a simplified example to better see the problem. You can easily replace ThemedDataGrid with DataGrid if you don't have ActiPro

Comment: Just so I am clear, in your new example, the proplem is that the text on the "shorter" headers isn't at the top? Or that it doesn't span the Grid space? Everything else looks like your picture.

Comment: The problem is that the text in the first row do not align among all columns and the same for the content of the second row (combobox). The way I wanted to do it is to align the text in the first row to the top of the header and the second row (combobox) to the bottom of the header to make sure all texts and comboboxes are at the same level among columns.

Comment: While degugging this I navigated the VisualTree and noticed that the Grid inside my header (in my xaml) gets created inside a ContenPresenter which has the VerticalAlignment set to "Center".
Is there a way to change that through XAML?

Comment: Using a control template, yes. If the template is simple enough just create a new style for your columnHeader that has a modified control template with the content presenter's vertical alignment modified.

Comment: You could, of course, also manually set the row heights for each header if you aren't going to change them all that often.